# Get addin instance handle in SolidWorks (SetAddinCallbackInfo2)

Tags: c#, .net, solidworks

I am writing a addin for SolidWorks using .NET(C#) and I am having trouble deciphering the SolidWorks API documentation.

In the add in template there is a call to ISldWorks.SetAddinCallbackInfo2 that sets the callback information for the library, from the [API documentation](https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ISldWorks~SetAddinCallbackInfo2.html) the signature is:

```
System.bool SetAddinCallbackInfo2( 
   System.long ModuleHandle,
   System.object AddinCallbacks,
   System.int Cookie
)
```

The `ISwAddin` implementation requires two functions to connect to the SolidWorks instance `bool ConnectToSW(object ThisSW, int cookie)` and  `bool DisconnectFromSW()` inside the `ConnectToSW` function is where the SetAddinCallbackInfo2 is called. The C# template provided by SolidWorks looks like:

```
public bool ConnectToSW(object ThisSW, int cookie)
{
   addinID = cookie;
   iSwApp = (ISldWorks)ThisSW;

   // Setup callbacks
   iSwApp.SetAddinCallbackInfo2(0, this, addinID);

   // Setup the command manager
   CmdMgr = iSwApp.GetCommandManager(addinID);

   AddCommandMgr();

   SwEventPtr = (SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.SldWorks)iSwApp;
   openDocs = new Hashtable();
   AttachEventHandlers();

   return true;
}
```

In my addin I want to structure my code so that callbacks are in classes further down the "Tree", meaning that I will have a couple of classes that will need `SetAddinCallbackInfo2` called to be able to set the callbacks within those classes. In the example above they are simply passing a `0` for the `ModuleHandle`, this seems to work if the `SetAddinCallbackInfo2` is called within the `ConnectToSW` function but not when called in other classes.

I don't have a ton of experience dealing with COM Interop, is the `ModuleHandle` supposed to be the handle of the current class instance calling `SetAddinCallbackInfo2` or the entry class that contains the `ConnectToSW` function? How do I get the `ModuleHandle`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a one class for handling all the Solidworks Api related stuff.
Purpose is to isolate all Solidworks Api related code there and keep rest of your code base focused on task at hand.

Then it would have public functions like :

```
public void SetAddinCallbackInfo(int id){
   iSwApp.SetAddinCallbackInfo2(0, this, id);
}
```

I also recomend doing classes for example Assembly, Part etc. that works between your app and SwDocument classes.